# How to create constraints about individuals (Protégé - OWL)

Tags: owl, protege, description-logic

I am creating an ontology in Protégé 5.5.0.

I have two classes: 'Person' and 'Company'. They can be related by the following properties:

- employs (inverse of isEmployedBy);
- manages (inverse of isManagedBy);
- sponsors (inverse of isSponsoredBy).

The classes are described as follows:

- Person is equivalent to:

  ```
  (isEmployedBy some Company)
  and (isSponsoredBy some Company)
  and (manages some Company)
  and (isEmployedBy only Company)
  and (isSponsoredBy only Company)
  and (manages only Company)
  ```
- Company is equivalent to:

  ```
  employs some Person
  and (isManagedBy some Person)
  and (sponsors some Person)
  and (employs only Person)
  and (isManagedBy only Person)
  and (sponsors only Person)
  ```

I would like to describe that if there is a Company(c) that employs Person(b), Company(c) can not sponsor Person(b), although it can sponsor Person(c) who is not employed by Company(c).
Since it is a rule related to the individuals and not to the classes I would like to know if it is possible to describe it as an axiom (with an example) or if I would have to use SWRL.

Comment: `DisjointProperties: employs, sponsors`? https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#a_DisjointObjectProperties

Comment: That's it! It worked as expected. Thank you!